Can we emulate a batch get type of query in Elastic search, what would be the time complexity?
I have a use case where I might need to query <18000 records by their primaryIds. Currently we have these records in a DynamoDb. We want to be able to get all these records under <1s. So far I have tried parallel batch gets using DynamoDB Enhanced SDK client which supporting non-blocking I/O client and are able to achieve a P100 of <0.5s or 500ms.
I want to explore another approach where if this same data is ingested into Elastic search we can you term queries to gather all the documents as well. Sample search code
GET /chemicals/_search

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "chemicalId": [
              "C0001",
              "C0002"
              ...
              "C18000"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "isActive": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size":10000
}

This is gives me overall latency under 1s as well with ES response object above stating processing time as 123ms. For context, this experiment is only done with 30K documents inserted in chemicals index, my first thought here is that since each of these checmicalIds are keyword type and will have at-most one document associated the time complexity for lookup is O(1) for all the 18K terms instead of O(logN) that I understand from various resources.
Could some help me understand if the understanding is wrong and as data size grows, the time complexity grows?
Some contextual background:

Eventual consistency is fine
Yes this does not look like a search problem but eventually we may need aggregation and filters for other use case, what I'm trying to understand is feasibility of getting this for free from ElasticSearch

